# aws ec2 public ip not at all working

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am very new to AWS. successfully launched EC2 windows 2012 r2 instance and i am able to login through remote desktop service. installed a nodejs app and it is successfully running on localhost:80. but, the problem is with public ip. i tried a lot of solutions posted around like adding inbound security rules and etc... i even terminated the instance and relaunched a new instance, but of no use.

server Details:
AWS EC2 : Windows 2012 R2

when ever i try to access via public dns, it says "webpage not availabe". my public ip is http://ec2-54-169-173-68.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com/

Here are the ping results:

```
C:\Users\srujan>ping ec2-54-169-173-68.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com

Pinging ec2-54-169-173-68.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com [54.169.173.68] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 54.169.173.68: bytes=32 time=51ms TTL=118
Reply from 54.169.173.68: bytes=32 time=51ms TTL=118
Reply from 54.169.173.68: bytes=32 time=49ms TTL=118
Reply from 54.169.173.68: bytes=32 time=43ms TTL=118

Ping statistics for 54.169.173.68:
Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss), Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
Minimum = 43ms, Maximum = 51ms, Average = 48ms
```

What does the ping results show?
Is the public ip working correctly?

Please let me know the solution. i was trying since many hours and left helpless. Let me know if any more details are required to solve the problem.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Fiddler Result in browser:

```
[Fiddler] The connection to 'ec2-54-169-173-68.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com' failed. 
Error: TimedOut (0x274c). 
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 54.169.173.68:80
```

Fiddler Result in Fiddler window:

```
Request Count:   1
Bytes Sent:      413        (headers:413; body:0)
Bytes Received:  719        (headers:207; body:512)

ACTUAL PERFORMANCE
--------------
ClientConnected:    09:38:03.718
ClientBeginRequest: 09:38:03.735
GotRequestHeaders:  09:38:03.735
ClientDoneRequest:  09:38:03.735
Determine Gateway:  0ms
DNS Lookup:         0ms
TCP/IP Connect: 21007ms
HTTPS Handshake:    0ms
ServerConnected:    09:38:24.745
FiddlerBeginRequest:    00:00:00.000
ServerGotRequest:   00:00:00.000
ServerBeginResponse:    00:00:00.000
GotResponseHeaders: 00:00:00.000
ServerDoneResponse: 00:00:00.000
ClientBeginResponse:    09:38:24.745
ClientDoneResponse: 09:38:24.745

Overall Elapsed:    0:00:21.009

RESPONSE BYTES (by Content-Type)
--------------
text/html: 512
~headers~: 207


ESTIMATED WORLDWIDE PERFORMANCE
--------------
The following are VERY rough estimates of download times when hitting  servers based in Seattle.

US West Coast (Modem - 6KB/sec)
    RTT:        0.10s
    Elapsed:    0.10s

Japan / Northern Europe (Modem)
    RTT:        0.15s
    Elapsed:    0.15s

China (Modem)
    RTT:        0.45s
    Elapsed:    0.45s

US West Coast (DSL - 30KB/sec)
    RTT:        0.10s
    Elapsed:    0.10s

Japan / Northern Europe (DSL)
    RTT:        0.15s
    Elapsed:    0.15s

China (DSL)
    RTT:        0.45s
    Elapsed:    0.45s


________________
Learn more about HTTP performance at http://fiddler2.com/r/?HTTPPERF
```

Comment: The ping indicates the public ip is fine. Use a tool like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to log what the [HTTP error code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) is and post it here with the details.

Comment: @GVashist : Hi, i have posted the results, please let me know the what the error is. By looking at the results, i guess there is a problem with port 80. Am i correct? if it is because of port 80, what will be the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem. its not with the port number or firewall. the problem is with the node.js program.

The error was:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(80, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:80/');
```

I changed it to:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen( 80 );
console.log('Server running at 80');
```

I just removed the localhost ip address. its working fine.

However, Thanks for your quick response and support.

Comment: I had the same problem...why??

Comment: I was having the same trouble with node not responding to requests to the listen(port) from the external elasticIP.  Turned out i needed to add UDP rules to the local firewalld as well as my ec2 security group.  Id thought it used TCP.

Comment: If you remove the 127.0.0.1 the port 80 will bind and respond to all Ip's locally, which might have fixed the problem, for example 0.0.0.0, 127.0.0.1, 54.169.173.68, hostname, localhost etc

Answer (score 0):

`ping` only tells you that the instance is accepting and replying to `icmp` packets. Its helpful in determining if there are issues with the route, but does not help you identify all problems.

Your problem comes down to one of two likely options:

1. A firewall is blocking the connection to port 80. This can include both the security group and windows internal firewall.
2. Your web server is not bound to the network interface. Web servers can be configured to bind to a single IP provided by an interface, or listen to all of them. You can also bind a site to loopback which makes it only accessible to itself.